# How could I remove sub-contents of the result of find command on linux

Tags: linux, shell, find

I know I could find the files or directories with `Linux` command:

```
find ./ -name '*build*'
```

and I know I could delete it with `-exec` option:

```
find ./ -name '*build*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The problem is that I need to keep the folder of build but to delete all its contents. Such that I will have some empty `build/` directories left.

How could I do this then ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-execdir` to execute something in the directory where a match was found.

```
find . -name '*build*' -execdir sh -c 'rm -rf {}/*' \;
```

The (slighty fugly) subshell is required in order for the wildcard to only get expanded when the `-execdir` happens.

Comment: Thanks but it seems the key is to use ```sh -c```,  for I find this also works for me: ```find ./ -name 'build' -exec sh -c 'rm -rf {}/*' \;```. Is this a professional solution ?

Comment: That's fine as well actually, I added the `{}` as an afterthought but it expands to the full path so yes, this works fine as well.